# R gganimate smooth transition between levels of a factor

Tags: r, transition, gganimate, manual

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rmapshaper)
library(dplyr)
library(gganimate)

hr_sf <- readRDS(url("https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsf/gadm36_HRV_1_sf.rds"))
hr_sf_small <-hr_sf[,c(1,4,11)]
hr_sf_small$YEAR <- as.factor(2020)
hr_sf_small_2020 <- hr_sf_small 
hr_sf_small_2010 <- hr_sf_small 
hr_sf_small_2010$YEAR <- recode_factor(hr_sf_small_2010$YEAR, "2020"="2010")

hr_sf_bind <- rbind(hr_sf_small_2010,hr_sf_small_2020)
set.seed(100)
hr_sf_bind$FILL.VAR <-sample(rainbow(7),nrow(hr_sf_bind),rep=T)
hr_sf_bind_simp <- ms_simplify(hr_sf_bind, keep = 0.10, keep_shapes = TRUE)

ggplot(hr_sf_bind_simp) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = FILL.VAR), lwd=0.1, col="black") +
  labs(title="How to create fade-in/fade-out transitions between discrete states: {current_frame}") + 
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12, vjust=3)) +
  transition_manual(YEAR)
```

I've successfully created this animation of a geom_sf() plot that changes colour based on the factor variable FILL.VAR at two points in time 2010, and 2020 (as indicated in the YEAR variable).

What I'd like to know is how I can slowly blend the transition between the two states so that the first state (YEAR=2010) slowly becomes more transparent, while the second state (YEAR==2020) becomes more opaque at the same time. That is, rather than a quick jump between 2 frames I'd like to make that a smooth transition over several frames.

Thanks!